# HTML5 - Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create something like this below in picture.[image: This is what i want to create using html,css,bootstrap]

I want these green circles to not be a picture, I want to style them using css and want to create exactly the same as in picture. can you please help me with this.

[image]

I want this text go under these circles as in picture.

Thanks

Comment: Please share your code or working example of this.

Comment: please visit this website - http://www.melbournesilvercars.com.au/reservations.php

Comment: So you just want to replace green circle image with css ... right?

Comment: no, I actually want to create this whole layout in css. I am using twitter-bootstrap to create a layout of this website to make it responsive, But when i try to create it, i get almost the same result as in picture. but the text don't go under these circle. I want this text to go under these green circle as in picture.

Comment: I edited my question, please have a look.

Comment: The text already under the image.

Comment: No, it's under in this picture I captured from website. But it's not like this where I am developing it on local server.